# Consume custom service application in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, service-application

I followed [this tutorial](http://sharepointegg.blogspot.sg/2009/11/create-custom-service-application-in.html) and successfully created a custom service application in my sharepoint server, my question is how to consume it from another sharepoint solution, for example I created a new empty sharepoint project and added a new application page, how I can get access to strongly type service application object from the code behind of application page?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **Service Application Proxy** by using `SPServiceApplicationProxy`. You can see the video and sample code in [Creating Custom SharePoint 2010 Service Applications and Consumers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg543112%28v=office.14%29.aspx).